# Is it fibonacci series recursion or not? If not tell how

Tags: java

This code is for below 10 fibonacci numbers. But I want know this is recursion function or not. The basic formula for fibonacci series is `f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)`. Using this I want a fibonacci program. I tried this but time complexity is more that's the reason to little changes above program.

```
int n=10,i,f0=1,f1=1,f2;

for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
  System.out.println(f0);
  f2=f0+f1;
  f0=f1;
  f1=f2;
  f2=f0;
}
```

Comment: No, it is not recursion. What makes you think it is?

Comment: No **recursion** (= calling itself), yes **iteration** (= multiple steps).

Comment: [If you don't know what recursion is, take a look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272187/is-it-fabinocci-series-recursion-or-not-if-not-tell-how)

Answer (score 4):

Recursion is, by definition, a function calling itself (directly or indirectly).

Other that the `println()`, there are no function calls in your program. Therefore no, it is not recursive.

It is a simple iterative algorithm.

In fact, a straightforward recursive implementation would be not be a good choice for this problem as it would have exponential time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

It is iteration as you have for loop and you are not calling the same method over again and again. You would call as method as resursive if you had something like method calling to itself as below:

```
public int addNumbers(int number) {
    if (number <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return number + addNumbers(number - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not recursive because the function doesn't call herself

This one is:

```
int fib(int n){
  if(n<2)
    return n;
  return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

As you see the method `fib` call herself: `fib(n-1)` and `fib(n-2)`

Answer (score 0):

It is not recursion as there is no recursive call, neither directly nor indirectly. The evaluation is done iteratively based on result for smaller arguments (also termed as [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)). However, in this implementation not all intermediate results are kept, hence only a constant number of variables is needed.